# Ignore parent width or padding

Tags: html, css

How can I ignore a parents width?

Lets say i have a code looking like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="content-container">
   <h1>Subject</h1>    
   <p>More text</p>
   <p><img src="/someimg.png"></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 684px
}
```

I would also have set a padding instead of a width like:

```
padding-left:20%
padding-right20%
```

I then want my image to have a bigger width than the container it's inside.

```
#content-container img {
  width:1000px;
}
```

But this does now work, since the image won't go out of it's container.

Is there a solution for this other than using `position:absolute;` or some negative margin values?

Comment: Woops. That was just a mistake in the question. Not in my code. This is just an example.

Comment: You shouldnt be putting something in a container if it is meant to be bigger/outside the container. Just place it above or bellow the container.

Comment: I could help but I still don't understand what you are trying to achiev. Do you want the image to be bigger than the the div, would you like to adjust the image to the div size or would you like to adjust the div to the image size? Do you want padding  inside the div for the image have some spacing inside the div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the container width to be large

```
    #content-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

and change the image width

```
    #content-container img {
  width:100%;
}
```

your image width must be smaller than the container or be equal

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
#content-container img {width:100%;}
```